# override truediv in python

Tags: python, methods, overriding, division

In Python 2.7.5 I tried the following:

```
class compl1:
    def __mul__(A,B):
        adb=56
        return adb

    def __truediv__(A,B):
        adb=56
        return adb

u=compl1()
z=compl1()
print  u*z
print u/z
```

Why does only u*z work, while u/z gives:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'instance'
```

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2, unless you add:

```
from __future__ import division
```

the `__truediv__` hook is not used. Normally `__div__` is used instead:

```
>>> class compl1:
...     def __div__(self, B):
...         return 'division'
...     def __truediv__(self, B):
...         return 'true division'
... 
>>> compl1() / compl1()
'division'
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> compl1() / compl1()
'true division'
```

With the `from __future__` import, the old Python 2 `/` operator is replaced by the Python 3 behaviour instead, where *all* numeric division with that operator results in a float result. In Python 2, if you used two `int` values, you got floor division instead, which was confusing.